# How can I implement this plan in android studio?

Tags: android

I'm write this xml file for custom listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="right"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my output is this:

[image]

I want to change up output to this:

[image]

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to :

> android:layout_width="match_parent"

And then use :

> android:layout_gravity="right"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    android:layout_gravity="right"
```